# Javascript Active Refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I have here a number which should be refreshed in case something is change in the form selection directly, without a button.
Example:

```
        <div class="col">
          <label for="speicher3">SSD & HDD (3)</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="speicher3" name="speicher3">
            <option value="1">-</option>
            <option value="2">Samsung EVO 970 - 500GB (M.2 - SSD)</option>
            <option value="3">Samsung EVO 970 - 1TB (M.2 - SSD)</option>
            <option value="7">Corsair MP400 - 2TB (M.2 - SSD)</option>
            <option value="4">Datenplatte 1TB (HDD)</option>
            <option value="5">Datenplatte 2TB (HDD)</option>
            <option value="6">Datenplatte 3TB (HDD)</option>
          </select>
          </div>
          </div>
```

So Option 2 when it is select I Should directly get the value 2 in this Attribute:

```
        <p id="preis" name="preis">
          Gesamtpreis:
          </p>
```

And this is the function, I dont know why the interval is not working, I think im doing something wrong.
Maybe someone know why

```
var sum = 0;

setInterval(sum = document.getElementById("gpu").value,0.5);
setInterval(document.getElementById("preis").innerHTML = "Gesamtpreis: "  + sum,0.5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using setInterval wrong. setTimeout and setInterval receives a function as first parameter.

You have to use it like this:

```js
setInterval(() => {
    sum = document.getElementById("gpu").value
    document.getElementById("preis").innerHTML = "Gesamtpreis: "  + sum
}, .5);
```

This `() => {}` is an arrow function. Works similar as a function(){}

If you want to know more about arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Please, take a look at my answer, as this is not the right way to manage what you are trying to do. The answer of @AndréInocenti is correct, but in your specific case, use the onchange method. Do not use setInterval(), it can cause performance issues.

Comment: @NewCodeer Maned Wolf is right. SetInterval can cause several performance issues. His answer is more complete

Answer (score 2):

There is an important thing you have to know when dealing with setInterval() function and element changes in javascript.
Never use setInterval() to achieve the result you are trying to reach.
The setInterval() function will trigger every millisecond in your case and can cause performance issues on browsers.
As stated here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp
The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

In order to do what you want, use onchange() method on select:

```
<select class="form-control" id="speicher3" name="speicher3" onchange="changePreis();">
```

and in your javascript write:

```
<script>
    function changePreis(){
        var sum = 0;
        sum = document.getElementById("speicher3").value;
        document.getElementById("preis").innerHTML = "Gesamtpreis: "  + sum;
    }
</script>
```

Another important thing (don't use in this specific case).
If you want to use the setInterval() function, you have to use the following syntax:

```
setInterval(function(){sum = document.getElementById("speicher3").value;},0.5);
```

Take a look at some examples, like W3C schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Answer (score 0):

A better approach whould be to user the onChange attribute of select.

Working code

```
 <div class="col">
          <label for="speicher3">SSD & HDD (3)</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="speicher3" name="speicher3" onChange="javascript:update(event);">
            <option value="1">-</option>
            <option value="2">Samsung EVO 970 - 500GB (M.2 - SSD)</option>
            <option value="3">Samsung EVO 970 - 1TB (M.2 - SSD)</option>
            <option value="7">Corsair MP400 - 2TB (M.2 - SSD)</option>
            <option value="4">Datenplatte 1TB (HDD)</option>
            <option value="5">Datenplatte 2TB (HDD)</option>
            <option value="6">Datenplatte 3TB (HDD)</option>
          </select>
          </div>
```

```
function update(event) {
  document.getElementById("preis").innerHTML = "Gesamtpreis: "  + event.target.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For change add eventlistener to select like below to get current value

```
var sum = 0;
var speicher3 = document.getElementById("speicher3");
var preis = document.getElementById("preis");
speicher3.addEventListener("change", function() {
    sum = speicher3.value;
    preis.innerHTML = "Gesamtpreis: "  + sum;
});
```